# Double int conversion messup

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I have no idea of why this code snippet produces the following output when I try to multiply 2 int values. This might be too dumb but I just dont get it. I have pasted the code and the output here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String numstring = "12122";
    char[] numArray = numstring.toCharArray();
    int num =0;
    int index = 10;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=numArray.length-1;i>=0;i--){
      int ind = (int)(Math.pow(index,count));
      System.out.print(numArray[i]+"*"+ind);
      System.out.println(" prints as ----->"+numArray[i]*ind);
      count++;
    }
}
```

output:

```
    2*1 prints as ----->50
    2*10 prints as ----->500
    1*100 prints as ----->4900
    2*1000 prints as ----->50000
    1*10000 prints as ----->490000
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not multiplying two ints.  Your multiply an `int`, *ind*, with a `char`, `'2'`, whose ASCII value is `50` (at least in the first case).  You could use an `int[]`, or if you want to stick with the `char[]`, you could do the following:

```
System.out.println(" prints as ----->"+ Character.getNumericValue(numArray[i]) * ind);
```

Answer (score 0):

Characters are really integers under the hood, so for example, the character '2' has int value 50.

To see which integer corresponds to which character, check out the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

To do what you want, you should use [Character.getNumericValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) method:

```
System.out.println(" prints as ----->"+Character.getNumericValue(numArray[i])*ind);
```

Comment: urgghhh..I hate myself fr this...thanks for pointing this out